# NFS Datastore in VMWare Server 2 on Ubuntu Server amd64

Tags: ubuntu, nfs, vmware-server

OK so here's the problem.

I'm running 4 Dell PowerEdge 3850 Servers on Ubuntu Server amd64 with VMWare Server 2.0. I want to setup a centralized NFS so all my vm's live there and I can be able to run them on any of my VMWare Server servers. The problem is that everytime I reboot Ubuntu server, the nfs datastore becomes unavailable. Im mounting the nfs exports via fstab and I've checked, it is mounting correctly.

VMWare datastore section marks my nfs mounted datastore with the free space of my local file system. If I force a datastore refresh I get the nfs free space but my vm is already unreachable. I need to delete it and add it again. Don't need to tell you that that is not working for me.

Thanks

Comment: I can't think for the life of me why you're not using ESXi for this instead, it doesn't sound like you're running anything else of significance on your actual hosts and ESXi *loves* NFS.

Comment: Thank you, is ESXi free? I've got NO budget for SW :S

Comment: You need to request a serial number from VMware but it is free.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I agree with Chopper and esxi would reduce the overhead being used by Ubuntu and VMware Server 2.

On to your question though, my thought is that the vmware service is being started before the nfs service can get the exports loaded. Perhaps one of these two will help?

1. if the nfs and vmware services both have a startup order of S01, perhaps you can change the vmware startup to S02, this would be done in your /etc/rc5.d
2. try delaying the startup of your vmware service by adding something like "sleep 10" to the beginning of the script...

Cheers!

Comment: Thanks guys, is ESXi free? I've got no budget to buy SW. And I tried restarting vmware server when i knew that the nfs was already mounted and it didnt help. the only thing that helps is refreshing the datastore from inside vmware webgui.